# Java - Grouping of common array elements

Tags: java, json

Am trying to group all the common array elements. For example

```
array = [{ 'LA',1},
         { 'LA',1},
         { 'NY',2},
         { 'NY',3},
         { 'LA',1}]
```

From this Array , am trying to group all the ONE element in one group and TWO element in another group and THREE also.

Please find the below code that that i made in javascript but, how can i make the same functionality using java

Java Script: - ( Am able to grouping it properly )

```
Arrays.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.number] = grouped[a.number] || [];
    grouped[a.number].push(a);
    });
```

Java :- ( but its not looping properly )

```
for(int i=0;i<lineItemsArray1.length();i++)
    {
    JSONObject lineObj1 = lineItemsArray1.getJSONObject(i);
    for(int j=i+1;j<lineItemsArray2.length();j++)
    {
    JSONObject  lineObj2 = lineItemsArray2.getJSONObject(j);
    if(lineObj1.getString("number").
    equalsIgnoreCase(lineObj2.getString("number")))
    {
     System.out.println("Number from OuterLoop ---
       >"+lineObj1.getString("number")+":::from InnerLoop ---
       >"+lineObj2.getString("number"));
         //int numbers=Integer.parseInt(lineObj1.getString("number"));
    }
    }
                }
```

For the mentioned Array, am expecting results like :

```
    Number from OuterLoop --->1:::from InnerLoop --->1
    Number from OuterLoop --->1:::from InnerLoop --->1
    Number from OuterLoop --->1:::from InnerLoop --->1
    Number from OuterLoop --->2:::from InnerLoop --->2
    Number from OuterLoop --->3:::from InnerLoop --->3
```

But am getting results like : ( which is not correct )

```
    Number from OuterLoop --->1:::from InnerLoop --->1
    Number from OuterLoop --->1:::from InnerLoop --->1
    Number from OuterLoop --->1:::from InnerLoop --->1
```

Comment: Could you post your exact expected result?

Comment: Added `Expected results` & `results am getting now`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i got the way to group common JSONArray elements.

```
Map<Object, List<JSONObject>> numberMap = IntStream.range(0, lineItemsArray.length())
                .mapToObj(index -> (JSONObject) lineItemsArray.get(index))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.get("number")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is this

```
Map<String, List<JSONObject>> map = IntStream.range(0, lineItemArray.size())
    .mapToObj(lineItemArray::getJSONObject)
    .groupingBy(item -> item.getString("number"));
```

which for your example gives you a `Map` containing

```
["1" = [{"1", "LA"}, {"1", "LA"}, {"1", "LA"}],
 "2" = [{"2", "NY"}],
 "3" = [{"3", "NY"}]]
```

(which is neither valid JSON nor actual `Map#toString` output, but I guess it's clear what is meant).

Comment: am getting this error `The method groupingBy((<no type> item) -> {}) is undefined for the type Stream<JSONArray>` in the .groupingBy() method.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Ooops I think it's due to the Map's type, should be `String` for `getString()`. Should work now.

Comment: `lineItemsArray` is an JSONArray . `JSONArray lineItemsArray =orderObject.getJSONArray("items");`

Comment: @Karthikeyan adjusted the answer. Not really used to working with json.

Comment: `.size()` is not available instead i changed to `.length()`. But am getting the below error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getJSONObject(int) from the type JSONArray` in .mapToObj() method.